# Can you help me to arrange some cards in a web page with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to arrange some cards, in a web page with Boostrap 4.
Can you help me?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
                card 01
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
    card 01
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
            card 03
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-4 ">
            <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
                card 04
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm Tried to make **[bootstrap 4 card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/)**  like a below image , but my card is not perfect, any idea for how to do correctly this one?

My code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12  ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
                card 01
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-4 ">
            <div class=" col-xl-3 col-lg-6 "><div class="card shadow-sm mb-0  bg-primary">
                card 01
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as below snippet in Bootstrap-v4.

**[Check on Full Page]**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 py-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary h-100 rounded-0 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4  py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 py-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary rounded-0 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use container and row which based bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/). To makes sure your cards are placed right position, Here my sample code (**Please run as full screen**) the result should be like this image
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>

<div class="container" style="width: 1240px !important; max-width: 960px !important;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; height: 100%">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">text</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card" style="width: 200px;">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">text</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use flex classes to achieve what you described.

```
<style>
    .box-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .box-2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 210px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="mr-3">
            <div class="box-2">card 01</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="mr-3">
            <div class="box-1">card 02</div>
            <div class="box-1 mb-0">card 05</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mr-3">
            <div class="box-1">card 03</div>
            <div class="box-1 mb-0">card 06</div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <div class="box-1">card 04</div>
            <div class="box-1 mb-0">card 07</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should refer the grid system of bootstrap

**(Run as full size)**

---

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.5.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary h-100 p-2 m-1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From your code to not proper gapping between cards. You can check on both small+wide screen view.

Answer (score 1):

To get that grid system you will need to create a grid of your own. You can do this with columns and rows. You can have columns inside of rows, and move each column or row to where you want it. I outlined the basic structure in the snippet below (I used some sample content from [G.W Kalpa Sathjana De Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65120856/14767390)'s code)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary h-100 p-2 m-1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary p-2 m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```